# What is known about the Gaussian measure of the unit ball in a Hilbert Space?

Tags: pr.probability, hilbert-spaces, fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ be an infinite dimensional separable Hilbert Space with norm $||\cdot||$ and let $\mu$ be a Gaussian measure on $X$ such that $\mu(X) = 1$.  What do we know about $\mu(B(0,1))$, where $B(0,1)$ is the unit ball w.r.t the norm?

This seems to me like a fundamental question but I cannot seem to find anything.  Any information/references would be most appreciated.

EDIT: A related question which is of interest to me:  Do there exist asymptotically tight bounds to 
$\int_{||u||> K}||u||^2 \mu(du)$?

Comment: I note that the OP only says that $\mu$ is supposed to be *a* Gaussian measure on $X$, which is a perfectly well-defined notion; but the answers so fare are written as if the OP asked about *the* Gaussian measure, which is not.  Of course, the answer to this will depend on the mean and covariance of $\mu$.

Comment: Look at the title of this question. I address both "the" Gaussian measure and "a" Gaussian measure in my answer.

Comment: Good point, I didn't pay close attention to the title.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't talk about "the" Gaussian measure on an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space, for the same reason that you can't talk about a uniform probability distribution over all integers. It doesn't exist; see Richard's answer. However, there are a lot of non-uniform Gaussian measures on infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces.

Consider the measure on $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ where the $j$th coordinate is a Gaussian with mean 0 and variance $\sigma_j^2$, where $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \sigma_j^2 < \infty$ (and different coordinates are independent). This is almost surely bounded in the $\ell_2$ metric, and any projection onto a finite-dimensional space has a Gaussian distribution. The squared length of a vector drawn from this measure is a sum of squares of Gaussians, and so follows some kind of generalized $\chi$-square distribution. If I knew more about generalized $\chi$-square distributions, I might be able to tell you what the measure of the unit ball was.

This kind of Gaussian distribution is very important in quantum optics. In fact, in quantum optics, a thermal state is Gaussian, so "the" Gaussian measure actually makes some sense.

Comment: Ok, your definition of "a" Gaussian measure matches mine.  Sorry  if I'm asking a dumb question, but what does a "non-uniform" Gaussian mean exactly?

Thanks for the pointer on quantum optics, I am very interested in learning of  applications of probability on infinite dimensional spaces.

Comment: As regards the generalized chi-square distribution idea.  This is exactly what  I chasing, however even on finite dimensional spaces the generalized chi-squared distribution has a quite complicated pdf, and things become hairy quite fast.

Comment: By "non-uniform" I meant that the variance isn't the same in all dimensions. I don't think this is standard terminology. I also think you're stuck with the generalized $\chi$-squared distribution, unfortunately.

Comment: Aha! This is much clearer!  Yes, of course, such a "uniform" Gaussian could not exist.  In fact, you would need the variances in all dimensions to have a finite sum, which is equivalent to saying that the Covariance operator of the Gaussian measure is trace class.

So, given a positive symmetric trace class operator, there is a Gaussian measure that has that covariance operator, however I think what you lose is unitary invariance,  e.x if I permute the basis elements the corresponding Gaussian will be different.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Sazonov's theorem</a> is a somewhat fancier way of saying what Peter Shor wrote in his answer; see
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sazonov_theorem

Answer (score 7):

In the book [Kazhdan’s Property (T)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publications.html?pg1=MR&s1=MR2415834) (Appendix A7) by Bekka, de la Harpe and Valette the symmetric Fock space on a Hilbert space is $H$ studied as the analogue of a space of measurable functions on a Hilbert space $H$. This is called the *Gaussian construction* and quite important if one wants to pass from unitary representations of a group $G$ to actions of $G$ on a probability measure space. This is probably not quite what you want, but serves as a suitable replacement of the Gaussian measure (on a finite-dimensional Hilbert space) for many purposes.

In case $H$ is finite-dimensional, it precisely corresponds to the study of the Gaussian measure on $H$. Here, the correspondence is clear: If $G$ acts by unitary operators on $H$, then it preserves the Gaussian measure $\mu$ on $H$ and hence, there is an associated action on the probability space $(H,\mu)$.

Answer (score 6):

There is no Gaussian measure on an infinite dimensional Hilbert space, or rather the Gaussian measure is identically zero. (Proof:  If the Gaussian measure of a ball of radius r on a 1-dimensional Hilbert space is c<1, then that of a ball in n dimensional is less than c<sup>n</sup>, so in infinite dimensions any ball has measure 0, so the measure of the whole space is 0.)  You can put a non-zero Gaussian measure on a larger space (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigged_Hilbert_space) and the unit ball of Hilbert space is a subset of this, but has measure 0 by the above argument.

Comment: Ok, there is something I am missing.  Many books define a Gaussian measure on a Hilbert space $H$ to be a measure such that the push forward measure of every linear functional on $H$ is Gaussian on $\mathbb{R}$.  One can then define the mean and covariance of the measure from the mean and variance of these real-valued distributions.

So this isn't a Gaussian measure in some sense?

Comment: And yet, your reasoning is perfect... :(  Are there non equivalent definitions of Gaussian measures on Hilbert Spaces.

Comment: See my answer for the definition of Gaussian measures on Hilbert spaces: one equivalent definition is that any projection onto a finite-dimensional space must be a Gaussian (with some covariance matrix $\Sigma$).

Comment: Just to confirm: my answer is for the case of THE Gaussian measure, while Peter Shor's answer is for the case of A Gaussian measure.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can see the articles
entitled "concentration of measure phenomenon ". The idea is as
follows: Let $(X,d,\mu)$ be a metric measure space, such as
$\mu(X)=1$. Let
$$\alpha(\epsilon) = \sup {\mu(X \backslash A_\epsilon) \  | \ 
\mu(A) = 1/2 }$$ where
$$A_\epsilon = { x \  | \  d(x, A) < \epsilon }$$ is
the $\epsilon$-extension of a set $A$. The function $\alpha(.)$ is
called the concentration rate of the space $E$. The following
equivalent definition has many applications:$$\alpha(\epsilon) =
\sup { \mu( { F >= M + \epsilon }) },$$ where the supremum is
over all $1$-Lipschitz functions $F: X \to \mathbb{R}.$ For example
the median (or Levy mean) $M = \mathop{Med}(F) $ is defined by the
inequalities $$\mu ( F \geq M ) >= 1/2, \  \mu ( F <= M ) \geq
1/2.$$ More precisely, the space $X$ exhibits a concentration
phenomenon if $\alpha(\epsilon)$ decays very fast as $\epsilon$
grows. More formally, a family of metric measure spaces
$(X_n,d_n,\mu_n)$ is called a Levy family if the corresponding
concentration rates $\alpha(\epsilon)$ satisfy
$$\forall \epsilon > 0 \ \  \alpha_n(\epsilon) \to 0,$$ and a normal
Levy family if $$ \forall \epsilon \to 0 \ \  \alpha_n(\epsilon) =
O(\exp(-C n \epsilon^2))$$ for $C$ some positive constant. the last
inequality is obtained bay applying the "Hoeffding inequality" and in
the  case of  Hilbert space with concentration in small balls we do :
$$\forall (x_1,x_2)\in X^2, \ \  d(x_1,x_2)=\|x_1,x_2\|< r.$$

Comment: For more detail, you can see the book of Michel Ledoux - "The Concentration of Measure Phenomenon. 


Comment: Or, the site :
http://books.google.fr/books?id=mCX_cWL6rqwC&printsec=frontcover&dq=The+Concentration+of+Measure+Phenomenon+%22ledoux%22&source=bl&ots=jkc8aeB1ul&sig=Kt3YPoDipEpzTJp3T_wJK-ZhwFI&hl=fr&ei=o7t0TPiUJJGUjAfCn7W8Bg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false