# Extending GUE to a measure on operators?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, random-matrices, hermitian

Let $\mathcal H_n$ denote the space of Hermitian $n\times n$ matrices and let $\mu_{GUE}$ denote the following measure on $\mathcal H_n$:
$$
\mu_{GUE}(dM) = \exp\left( -\frac{n}{2}\text{tr}\ M^2\right)\ dM,
$$
where $dM$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on $\mathcal H_n$. For fixed $n$,  $\mu_{GUE}$ has finite mass. The resulting normalized measure is the GUE ensemble studied in Random Matrix Theory.

**Question:** Can this measure be extended to the space of self-adjoint operators?

**Fuzzy question:** Do people study Gaussian ensembles of random self-adjoint operators?

Comment: I'm not sure but wouldn't that measure pick up only the zero matrix?

Comment: The only measure I've defined is $\mu_{GUE}$ for finite $n$. This is clearly not a Dirac measure. Are you referring to a potential extension of the measure to the space of self-adjoint operators?

Comment: pre-kidney indeed

Comment: What's the difference between a matrix and an operator?

Comment: The point is to extend the measure from a finite-dimensional manifold to an infinite-dimensional manifold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of looking at this is that, up to normalization, the GUE is standard Gaussian measure on the space of Hermitian matrices, equipped with the Hilbert-Schmidt or Frobenius inner product.  So what you're asking for is a special case of extending the notion of standard Gaussian measure to a particular infinite-dimensional space.  But [you can't do that.](https://mathoverflow.net/a/36417/1044)

Answer (score 2):

A classic problem in this connection is to derive GOE or GUE statistics for the spectrum of a random self-adjoint operator of the form $H=-\nabla^2 + V(\vec{r})$, in some bounded domain of $\mathbb{R}^3$. The measure is the Gaussian measure for $V(\vec{r})$, of zero mean and given two-point correlation function. Since this is a real operator, one would expect GOE statistics, to obtain GUE statistics one would replace $\nabla\mapsto \nabla+i\vec{B}\times\vec{r}$ for some given vector $\vec{B}$.

This problem was solved by Konstantin Efetov in 1982, as described in much detail in his book on [Supersymmetry in Disorder and Chaos.](https://books.google.nl/books?id=E4qpedgudPEC) The GOE or GUE statistics is found to hold only over a limited range $E_{0}$ (the so-called [Thouless energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thouless_energy)): eigenvalues that differ by more than $E_0$ become uncorrelated, reverting to Poisson statistics.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean Free Probability Theory (See e.g. Voiculescu, D. V.; Dykema, K. J.; Nica, A. Free random variables. A noncommutative probability approach to free products with applications to random matrices, operator algebras and harmonic analysis on free groups) ?

Comment: Please be more specific. At the moment I am learning about free probability, which is what inspired this question.